# declare bean with @Bean in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am just getting started with Spring (Boot).

I have my "main" class in `abc.de`, annotated with `@SpringApplication`.

So far, everything works fine. I have only used stereotype annotations.

Now I would like to use `@Bean` with an `@Configuration` class, just to see how it works.

My `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public XslDataFileLoader dataSource() {
        return new XslDataFileLoader();
    }
}
```

The class `XslDataFileLoader` is in the same package.

I declare this bean with `@Autowired` in a controller class.

So my "main" class is in `abc.de`, the config class is in `abc.de.config` and the XslDataFileLoader is in `abc.de.config` as well.

When I start the application, spring cannot inject the bean. It doesn't find it.

I tried `scanPackages = abc.de.config`: That way, none of my other beans are found.

How do I need to declare this in the latest spring boot?

**EDIT**

*Stacktrace:*

```
2017-05-19 13:52:03 ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field dataSource in abc.de.controllers.LoginController required a bean of type 'abc.de.config.XslDataFileLoader' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'abc.de.config.XslDataFileLoader' in your configuration.
```

*XslDataFileLoader:*

```
package abc.de.config;

public class XslDataFileLoader {
    public XslDataFileLoader() {

    }
}
```

*LoginController:*

```
package abc.de.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import abc.de.config.XslDataFileLoader;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    XslDataFileLoader loader;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        System.out.println(loader);
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String loginTry() {
        return "redirect:dashboard";
    }
}
```

**2ND EDIT**

*MySpringBootApplication:*

```
package abc.de;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class MySpringBootApplication{

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

*application.properties:*

```
server.port=5566
spring.application.name=@project.name@
# data source
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
# Session
spring.session.store-type=none
# Security
security.basic.enabled=false

# logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
#logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
logging.level.=error
```

Comment: have you put @configuration or @ component on XslDataFileLoader ?

Comment: @pvpkiran No, I have not. See my edit

Comment: If you don't have any of these annotations, Spring cannot recognize it as a bean. So it cannot autowire

Comment: @pvpkiran That is not the case as he declared it in a `BeanConfiguration`, there is something else going on

Comment: The bean you have declared has no name. And when you autowire spring is trying to autowire by name `loader`. It cannot find a bean with id as `loader`. Try giving a name to your bean declared in `BeanConfiguration` something like this `@Bean(name = "loader")` or rename the variable in your controller as  `xslDataFileLoader`

Comment: @pvpkiran that is also not the case, the bean can be loaded by class type unless specified by `@Qualifier` then it will be by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please post all of your code and the stacktrace.

The `BeanConfiguration` class is configured correctly so something is probably wrong with your injection.

Do you have annotations on `XslDataFileLoader` class? It might be a problem of double beans declaration and not bean not found (if you have both a `@Component` on `XslDataFileLoader` and at the same time declared it in `BeanConfiguration`)

Comment: I also have @EnableJpaRepositories in my "main" class... but that won't be it, will it?

Comment: Can you also post the code for your main `@SpringBootApplication` class

Comment: It might be something with the name `dataSource` as `spring data` create a default bean with this name. try using another name for your `XslDataFileLoader` bean

Comment: Ah that was from before, I first had a DataSource declared there. I did change the field name later.

Comment: so in `BeanConfiguration` it is declared as `public XslDataFileLoader loader()` and you `@Autowire` -> `XslDataFileLoader loader;`?

Comment: Nope, that was it! The method name was not loader. I didn't know it had to have the same method name. Thanks!